# Why I cannot assign a data property to a variable in a methods function like this in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The variable `state` seems cannot to linked to the data property. It would great if someone can clarify this!

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",

data: {
    seen: true,
    show: 'visible',
    hide: 'hidden',
    pStyle: {
        visibility: "hidden"
    }
},

methods: {
    toggler: function () {
        var state = this.pStyle.visibility;
        if (state === this.show) {
            state = this.hide;
        }
        else {
            state = this.show;
        }
    }
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <p  v-if="seen" v-bind:style="pStyle">Now you see me!</p>
 <p>Now you cant see me!</p>
 <button @click="toggler">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When you assign `var state = this.pStyle.visibility;` you basically assign `var state = true | false`, based on `this.pStyle.visibility` value at the time of the assignment. When later on you assign something else to `state`, `this.pStyle.visibility` doesn't change (and it really shouldn't!). Also, if you change `this.pStyle.visibility`, `state` doesn't change. Technically, you don't assign a reference to `this.pStyle.visibility` to `state`. You are only assigning its current value. What you expect only happens with objects, not with primitive values, like strings, booleans or numbers.

Comment: Super helpful!!!!!! Thanks so much, tao!